# GCD in polynomial rings with coefficients in a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $E/F $ be a field extension and $f,g$ $\in$ $F[x]$ (the polynomial ring with coefficients in $F$ ). Let's denote with $\gcd_F(f,g)$ the greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$ in $F[x]$. Is it true that $\gcd_F(f,g)$ $=$ $\gcd_E(f,g)$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a slightly different perspective to the posted answers: As Bill Dubuque observes in his answer, by dividing $f$ and $g$ through by their GCD, you can reduce to the case where $f$ and $g$ are coprime (i.e. have GCD equal to $1$),
and then you have to show that they remain coprime in $E[x]$.

One can certainly deduce this using the Euclidean algorithm (more precisely, one can find $h(x)$ and $k(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f h + g k = 1$, and this equation
persists in $E[x]$, showing that $f$ and $g$ are coprime in that ring as well),
but one can also deduce this from the fact that coprime polynomials have no common zero in $\overline{F}$ (the algebraic closure of $F$), hence have no common zero in $\overline{E}$ (the algebraic closure of $E$) either, and hence remain coprime in $E[x]$.

Also: see this [question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83247/221) for another discussion of the  persistence of coprimality under field extensions. (The preceding paragraph
is essentialy a summary of those answers.)

Answer (score 12):

Hint: You compute the gcd with the Euclidean algorithm, right?

Comment: Thank you...the euclidean algorithm depends only on $f$ and $g$ and therefore yields the same solution in $E[x]$.

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci: Correct. Well done.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ $ It follows rather trivially from the fact that properties that are definable by the existence of solutions to ring equations necessarily persist in extension rings. Thus the property of being a *common divisor* clearly persists in extension domains, and the property of being a *greatest* common divisor also persists since it follows from the fact the the gcd is representable as linear combination (Bezout identity), and this identity necessarily persists in extensions.

In detail: gcds in a PID D persist in extension rings because the gcd may be specified by the solvability of (linear) equations over D,  and such solutions always persist in extension rings, i.e. roots in D remain roots in rings $\rm\,R \supset D.\:$ More precisely, the [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) for the gcd yields the following ring-theoretic *existential $(\exists_1)$ equational specification* for the gcd

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\gcd(a,b) = c &\iff&\rm (a,b) = (c)\\
&\iff&\rm  a = c\:\color{#C00}x ,\  b= c\:\color{#C00} y ,\,\ a\:\color{#C00} u + b\: \color{#C00}v = c\ \  has\ roots\ \ \color{#C00}{x,y,u,v}\in D\end{eqnarray}$$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\:$ In any ring $\rm R,\:$  $\rm\:a\: x = c,\ b\: y = c\:$ have roots $\rm\:x,y\in R$ $\iff$ $\rm c\ |\ a,b\:$ in $\rm R.$ Further if $\rm\:c = a\: u + b\: v\:$ has roots $\rm\:u,v\in R\:$ then $\rm\:d\ |\ a,b$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:d\ |\ a\:u+b\:v = c\:$ in $\rm\: R.\:$ Hence we infer $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in $\rm\: R,\:$ being a common divisor divisible by every common divisor. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ If $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in D then the Bezout identity  implies the existence of such roots $\rm\:u,v\in D. $

**Remark** $ $ While this is true for all purely *existential* $(\exists_1)$ properties it does not hold true for more general properties. E.g. *universal* $(\forall)$ properities (laws) generally do not persist, e.g. an extension ring of a commutative ring need not be commutative. Such persistence properties are studied at length when one studies model theory = universal algebra + logic.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The coefficients of the Bezout identity are the same in $E$ and $F$ since in both cases they are obtained with the euclidean algorithm. Still, without the euclidean algorithm (which isn't necessary to define the gcd in a ring) I wouldn't know how to procede. Did you have something else in mind? I still find it quite interesting that no matter how "large" the extension $E|F$ is, there is no improvement on the gcd of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci The answer does not employ the Euclidean algorithm. It works over any PID, and PIDs need not be Euclidean.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=\gcd_F(f,g)$. Then $$dE[x]=(dF[x])E[x]=((f,g)F[x])E[x]=(f,g)E[x].$$Thus $d=\gcd_E(f,g).$

Comment: Although the proof is almost identical to the existing answers, somehow the way this answer is written sticks to my brain the best; and may be some feel the same way. Hence this answer.