# how to prove that HCF of two integers will always be an integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Although the  definition of HCF for any given integers , on wikipedia clearly mentions it to be the largest positive integer which divides the given integers , I wanted to prove that even if we say HCF to be the largest positive real number which divides the given integers then also it has to be an integer always . For proving this I used the concept that if 'a' is divisible by 'b' (where 'a' and 'b' are any two real numbers and b is not 0 ) this means a/b is an integer . But I could not succeed in it . Please guide me by proving the above fact for any two positive integers 'a' and 'b' .

Comment: What does it mean for a real number to divide an integer?  More specifically, when would it *not* divide an integer?

Comment: HCF means gcd, right?

Comment: Hint:  If $\frac mn$ divides $a$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then show that $m$ divides $a$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux And I thought that gcd meant hcf.

Answer (score 1):

Under the definition you use, if a real number $x$ divides an integer $a$ then $x$ must be rational (clearly).

The desired claim then follows quickly from the fact that, if $\frac mn$ is written in reduced form, then $$\frac mn\,|\,a\implies m\,|\,a$$

Pf:  by your definition we know that there is an integer $k$ with $\frac mn\times k=a$ hence $$mk=an$$

Thus $m\,|\,an$.  But $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime (by assumption), hence, by Bezout, $$m\,|\,an\implies m\,|\,a$$

Comment: In case people don't know, [pf is short for proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations).

Answer (score 0):

Integer gcds remain unchanged in the extension because each real divisor $\,\delta\,$ of an integer $\,k\,$ is $\rm\color{#0a0}{equivalent}$ to an integer divisor. Indeed,  $\,\delta\mid k\,$ means $\,k/\delta = j\in\Bbb Z,\,$ hence $\, \delta\in\Bbb Q,\,$ say $\delta = n/m,\ (n,m)=1.\,$ Then $\,\delta\mid k\iff n\mid mk\iff \color{#c00}n\mid k\,$ by Euclid, so we have

$$\ \ \delta\mid k\color{#0a0}\iff \color{#c00}{n_\delta}\mid k,\ \ {\rm for\ some }\,\ n_\delta\in\Bbb Z$$

therefore gcds in $\,\Bbb Z\,$ persist: $\ \delta\mid j,k\color{#0a0}\iff n_\delta\mid j,k\iff n_\delta\mid (j,k)\color{#0a0}\iff \delta\mid (j,k)$

i.e. the gcd $\,(j,k)\in\Bbb Z\,$ remains the gcd of $\,j,k\,$ in $\Bbb R$ with said extension of integer divisibility.

The same holds true for analogous extensions of any gcd-domain (in place of $\Bbb Z$ above).

Comment: Alternatively, gcd persistence [follows from the gcd Bezout equation,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84585/242) which works for any Bezout domain.