# Connection between irreducibility of a polynomial and GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to show that, if a polynomial in $F[x]$ is irreducible, then it has no repeated roots.

I showed that $(f, f') = 1$ iff $f$ has no repeated roots. I know that we can then write

$$
f(x)g(x) + f'(x)h(x) = (f, f')
$$
for some $g, h\in F[x]$.

I'm unsure why we can claim that $f(x)$ is then reducible because of this?

My confusion stems from here: if the GCD is independent of the field (if $f, g\in F[x]$, and $K$ is a field extension of $F$, and we consider $f, g$ as elements in $K[x]$ by denoting them $f', g'$, then $(f, g) = (f', g')$), then how do we know that $(f, f')$ is necessarily a polynomial in $F[x]$ and not $K[x]$ for some field extension?

If I can convince myself that the GCD of two polynomials always lies in the same polynomial ring, then the proof is finished because we have a contradiction wherein we have $$0 < \text{deg(gcd(}(f, f'))) \leq \text{deg}(f) - 1,$$ i.e., we have a nontrivial factor.

But part of me is unconvinced that there aren't irreducible real-valued polynomials both having $(x-i)$ as a factor. Or, in general, why $(x - \alpha)$ can't be a factor of some irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ where $K$ is a field extension of $F$ and $\alpha\in K$ but $\alpha\notin F$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84585/242). If that answers your question then please delete it since we already have too many questions on such matters.

Comment: @BrianMoehring oh yea, will edit

Comment: This: "a polynomial in $F[x]$ is irreducible, then it has no repeated roots" is not true in general.  Are there any additional assumptions you might have left out?  (In any context where the initial problem is false, $0 < \text{deg(gcd(}(f, f'))) \leq \text{deg}(f) - 1$ is also false)

Comment: You are using $f'$ in your question to denote both the formal derivative of $f$ and $f$ as an element of $K[x]$. You should not ever use the same symbol to mean two different things in the same context.