# Is the greatest common factor of two multivariate polynomials independent with field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $k$ is a field, I define the greatest common factor of two polynomials $f,g\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ as follows:

It's well known that $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is a UFD, let $$f=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{\alpha_i},g=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{\beta_i}$$ be irreducible decompositions. Then define $\mathrm{gcd}_k(f,g)=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{\mathrm{min(\alpha_i,\beta_i)}}$, this is the gcd of $f,g$ in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

Now my question is, suppose there is any field extension of $k\subset L$, naturally take $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ as a subring of $L[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, is $\mathrm{gcd}_k(f,g)=\mathrm{gcd}_L(f,g)$?

It's well known that this is true when $n=1$ (by Euclidean algorithm), but I don't know whether this is true for arbitrary n.

Comment: Hint: You wrote the irreducible decomposition of $f$ and $g$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Think how extending to $L[x_1,...,x_n]$ changes this decomposition, and so, does it change the gcd.

Comment: @Mark As your hint, this question can be reduced to the case that both $f$ and $g$ are irreducible in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, if both are irreducible then either their $\gcd$ is $1$, or one of the polynomials divides the other one.

Comment: @Mark If $f,g$ is irreducible in $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, why is $\mathrm{gcd}_L(f,g)$ must be $1$ or $f$?

Comment: You wrote in the question that you know that if $\gcd_K(f,g)=1$ then $\gcd_L(f,g)=1$ as well. And if $f|g$ then clearly the $\gcd$ in any field will be $f$.

Comment: @Mark I don't know this. I only know my question is true when the number of variables is 1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my mistake. Well, this part is nontrivial. You need some algebraic geometry. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500646/multivariate-coprime-polynomials-in-field-extensions

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the gcd does not work for zero polynomials, but the cases $\mathrm{gcd}(f,0)=f$ are of course easy to deal with. So let's assume $f,g \neq 0$ in $K[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$. Let $d  := \mathrm{gcd}_K(f,g)$. Then $f/d$, $g/d$ are coprime in $K[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$. By [Multivariate coprime polynomials in field extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500646) as mentioned by Mark in the comments (this is not straight forward!) $f/d$, $g/d$ are also coprime in $L[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$. Hence,
$$\mathrm{gcd}_L(f,g) = \mathrm{gcd}_L(d \cdot f/d, d \cdot g/d) = d \cdot \mathrm{gcd}_L(f,g) = d \cdot 1 = \mathrm{gcd}_K(f,g).$$
The converse is also true: your question implies that coprime polynomials over $K$ remain coprime over $L$. So the statement is equivalent to the linked question.

Comment: $(1)$ When you copy dupe arguments / links from comments please have the courtesy to give credit. $(2)$ Please don't answer duplicates.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, since my answer shows that some work is necessary to show the equivalence. I dont agree with your close action. The questions are different.

Comment: I have reopened accordingly.

Comment: Be serious, the "work" required to reduce the coprime is absolutely trivial. It is truly unfortunate that you choose to destroy abstract dupe organization this way.

Comment: For us its trivial, yes. Not for every reader opening this site.

Comment: Surely this elementary reduction is *utterly trivial* for any reader who is capable of comprehending the linked advanced arguments using commutative algebra / algebraic geometry. I can't imagine how you would seriously think otherwise. This should have been a dupe closing comment, not an answer.